# Is it always possible to find a nonce for target hash?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, nonce, consensus

I was wondering if it is always possible to find a nonce, while mining a block in a blockchain, for the target hash? Because nonce, being max. 32 bits, can only have 2^32 different possible values. What if we don't get our target hash for any nonce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Modify the timestamp of a block, here is a practice [Ntime Rolling](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/75948/ntime-rolling-is-just-an-optimization-for-large-fast-pools-correct). But it is not that sufficient now since a block will not be accepted if it's timestamp is not in a period(about 3 hours) of time, see [timestamp](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_timestamp).
2. Add/remove some transactions or alter the order of transactions as long as they are still in topological order (If transaction A spend one of the outputs of transaction B, then B must precede A in the transaction list)
3. Change the coinbase transaction. The prevout script of coinbase txinput is an arbitrary byte array of 2 to 100 bytes. This script will not be executed, so you can put any data you want. Note that it has to start with a byte of a correct push of the block height, see [bip34](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0034.mediawiki).

So basically you can say it's always possible to find a valid nonce with the combination of all of these above.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the nonce is only 1 part that is modified to generate a block hash. As you pointed out, since the nonce is only 32 bits, with today's difficulty, it is not enough to generate a valid block hash. Therefore, miners may also modify the coinbase transaction (sometimes called the extranonce), the block version, the merkle tree, and the block timestamp. See also [ASIC BOOST](https://www.asicboost.com/).